# How can I extract the name of a $_POST variable, not its value_

Tags: php

I am building a function that will validate the values in a form.
How can I extract the actual name in string form from a $_POST variable?
Ex: $_POST['first_name'] = 'Joe';

I now want to grab the string 'first_name' and use it in a function to declare a variable by that name. I know I can use a foreach loop but isn't there an easier way to do this?

Comment: "... declare a variable by that name" Don't do this. It is likely to cause a security vulnerability - e.g. if someone posts a variable called _COOKIE or _SERVER. It's why the PHP.ini option register_globals should always be turned off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood, you are looking for [`array_keys($_POST)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).

Answer (score 6):

How about

```
extract($_POST);
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution; there isn't any reason to loop through all the array values, when there is `extract()` that does all the work.

Answer (score 5):

```
foreach( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
     $$key = $value;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest useing the `${$key}` format but only to improve readability.  Thats entirely a personal preference though.

Comment: "`extract` puts the variables into global scope": plain false. I don't ever understand where you got it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether this is what you want, but you can use *variable variables* like so:

```
$fieldname = "first_name";

$fieldvalue = $_POST[$fieldname];

$$fieldname = $fieldvalue;   // Creates a variable named "first_name"

echo $first_name;  // Outputs the POST variable
```

Comment: Not actually.. I just wanted to use the text 'first_name' as the value of a new variable. So if I echoed $fn it would echo 'first_name'

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use this:

```
foreach( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
     $$key = $value;
}
```

...it opens your code to the possibility of someone maliciously setting vars within your program via the form. (i.e., effectively setting globals_register on)

But to answer your core question: your only knowledge of the posted variables is what's in the $_POST array; your only way of finding out what the variable names are is looping through the array keys.

Comment: a) it's what he asked for, and b) it's `register_globals` ;)

Comment: Er, yeah, register_globals. And you're right--actually let me refine that to: make sure you don't do that in global scope, and only inside a function. (which is also what you said, but it deserves emphasis)

Comment: I agree, globals are really really bad. But it's what the doctor ordered.

Comment: Well, if I clean the variable prior to assignment then shouldn't that be ok?

Comment: No, because the issue is someone setting variables that you don't intend to be set. (though I see the "extract" answer pretty much answers your question...lookup register_globals if you're curious about the security issue.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute function based on the key name, your best shot would be something like this:

```
foreach ($_POST AS $key => $value)
{
    call_user_func("example_func_$key", $value);
}
```

Note the use of `$key` within the double-quotes of the first parameter of `call_user_func`. This will allow you to execute a "dynamically" named-function.